# AttributeError at /account/login/oauth/complete/facebook/ 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'userprofile'

Tags: python, django, facebook, python-social-auth, django-socialauth

I have a problem, that instead of "User" Facebook account info is of "NoneType" type, so I can't save image as extended user model information (userprofile) after first facebook social authentication.

If any additional information is needed please give me a notice.

**settings.py:**

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE = ['email']
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_PROFILE_EXTRA_PARAMS = {
    'fields': 'id,name,email',
}

SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'social_core.pipeline.user.user_details',
    'ridemaker.pipeline.save_profile',
)
```

**pipeline.py:**

```
from accounts.models import UserProfile
from social_core.backends.facebook import FacebookOAuth2, FacebookAppOAuth2
from urllib.request import urlopen
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile

def save_profile(backend, details, response, uid,\
              user, *args, **kwargs):
    if backend.__class__ == FacebookOAuth2:
        url = "http://graph.facebook.com/%s/picture?type=large" % response['id']
        avatar = urlopen(url)
        #Why is user argument "None"?
        profile = user.userprofile
        profile.image.save(slugify(user.username + " social") + '.jpg',
                        ContentFile(avatar.read()))
        profile.save()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overriding the `SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE` in settings and have missed the pipeline `social_core.pipeline.user.create_user` which creates the user. Put below two pipelines after `social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_user` in `SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE`:

```
'social_core.pipeline.user.get_username',
'social_core.pipeline.user.create_user',
```